# TransferHttpCacheModule doesn't prevent duplicate HTTP Calls in Angular 8

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal

I've set up an Angular 8 Project with Angular Universal. To prevent duplicate HTTP Calls, Angular offers **TransferHttpCacheModule**.

I followed the official Documentation to add **TransferHttpCacheModule** to Angular (https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/docs/transfer-http.md)

I also tried to add the **BrowserTransferStateModule** (https://www.twilio.com/blog/faster-javascript-web-apps-angular-universal-transferstate-api-watchdog), but this doesn't work either.

**app.module.ts**

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {TransferHttpCacheModule} from "@nguniversal/common";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({appId: 'serverApp'}),
    TransferHttpCacheModule, // <-
    ...
    HttpClientModule
  ]
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**app.server.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {ServerModule, ServerTransferStateModule} from '@angular/platform-server';

import {AppModule} from './app.module';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {ModuleMapLoaderModule} from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
    ModuleMapLoaderModule,
    ServerTransferStateModule // <-
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppServerModule {
}
```

**main.ts**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  platformBrowserDynamic()
    .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
});
```

My Api Service
**api.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  private API_URL = '/api/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  public get<T>(url: string): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.get<T>(this.API_URL + url);
  }

  public post<T>(url: string, payload: T): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.post<T>(this.API_URL + url, payload);
  }

  ...

}
```

HTTP Call
**home.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ApiService} from "../../api.service";
import {Offer} from "../../offer-preview/offer.model";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.sass']
})
export class HomeOffersComponent implements OnInit {
  latestOffers: Offer[];

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.apiService.get<Offer[]>("offer")
      .subscribe(data => this.latestOffers = data);
  }

}
```

According to the official TransferHttpCacheModule Docs, the Browser should not make an XHR to **/api/offer**, but the i see the XHR Call in the Developer Network Tools.

What am i doing wrong? Did I miss anything?

Comment: I was able to solve it. The problem was that I used a relative path in **api.service.ts**. You need to use an absolute URL.

Comment: More info? how can you must use absolute paths? I need to keep relative to allow environments,.. could you explain that please?

Comment: I use absolute url's and still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

This is because of a mismatch between the absolute URLs the `TransferHttpCacheModule` is using as cache key for each request.
For example:

|  | Server | Client |
| --- | --- | --- |
| baseUrl | localhost:4200 | domain.com |
| ressource | /api/people | /api/people |
| Absolute URL | http://localhost:4200/api/people | https://example.com/api/people |

Only if both Absolute URLs are the same the request is successfully cached.
To circumvent this shortcoming you can implement your own caching via the `BrowserTransferStateModule` and Interceptors, e.g. as described [here](https://itnext.io/angular-universal-caching-transferstate-96eaaa386198).

Just be sure to only use the relative URL:

```
const url = new URL(req.url);
const rel = url.toString().substring(url.origin.length);
this.transferState.set(makeStateKey(rel), event.body);
```